# AWS EC2 Instance - How to add a Load Balancer to an Instance Application that already has an Elastic IP and SSL?

Tags: django, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-elb

I have an Ubuntu 18.04 LTS EC2 Instance with a deployed Django application. The instance also has an elastic IP. The Django application already has a domain name mapped to it in nginx, and it also already has an SSL certificate mapped using certbot.

My questions are:

1. Do I need to add an HTTPS listener to the load balancer? If yes, do I use the SSL generated by certbot? How?
2. Do I need to change the IPV4 that is in the nginx config file and DNS record with the new IPV4 of the load balancer created?

Answer (score 0):

1. Do I need to add an HTTPS listener to the load balancer? If yes, do I use the SSL generated by certbot? How?

Yes, you would need to create a HTTPS listener and you need to use a certificate, you can import the same certificate you're using on nginx or get a new certificate from ACM (free), both will work as long as the subject/SAN are correct.

2. Do I need to change the IPV4 that is in the nginx config file and DNS record with the new IPV4 of the load balancer created?
   ELB provided DNS name , the IP changes so you can't use IP address but after using ELB, you don't need elastic IP on EC2 instance , the communication between ELB and EC2 is on private IP so you can allow 0.0.0.0 in nginx and restrict ELB to make connections to ec2 instance, you will need to point your website to ELB DNS name eventually.

Comment: For #2, what will happen to the elastic IP that is currently associated with my instance after adding ELB? So you mean, I need to point my domain record to the new ELB DNS? For example, I have a Domain Name sample.net which points to my elastic ip, I need to change it to point to the new ELB DNS?

Comment: Yes, that how people will resolve to ELB and connect to it and elb neing proxy connects to your ec2 instance, careful with the changes :)